# Center vertically flexslider gallery

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering

I need to center vertically a gallery slider. I've created a class "centrary" that applies position relative, top 50% and translateY(-50%). But is not working because after applying that class the gallery stays in the top of the page. The gallery is inside a full-screen lightbox. So I need the gallery to be in the center of the screen no matter which is the size of the screen. May be I'm applying the class centrary to the wrong element.

This is the html code

```
<div id="openGallery" class="item-gallery ">
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close-gallery"><span class="icon-subastea-close"></span></a>
  <div class="large-8 large-centered medium-8 medium-centered columns">          
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="assets/images/1.png" class="centrary" alt="Foto 1"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/images/2.png" class="centrary" alt="Foto2"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/images/3.png" class="centrary" alt="Foto3"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/images/4.jpg" class="centrary" alt="Foto4"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>          
    <p class="image-counter"></p>         
  </div>
</div>
```

And this some css classes I'm using. Some of them are inherited from Flexslider library.

```
.item-gallery{
  background-color:$black-opacity-modal;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.flexslider {  
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  max-height: 31.25em; 
}

/* FlexSlider Default Theme */
.flexslider {
  margin: 0; 
  position: relative; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
  -o-border-radius: 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px; 
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
  zoom: 1;}

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles */ 
 .flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
 .flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
 .flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
 .flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

 /* Clearfix for the .slides element */
   .slides:after {content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
   html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;} 
   html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}

.centrary {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

[image]